# hide html controls when java script alert message popups

Tags: php, javascript, html, alert

I need to hide html controls like buttons, when alert message popups. As initially some controls are hidden but when alert message popups it shows the controls. How to make controls hidden when alert message popup. The below image shows the problem..

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function disableElements()
{
    document.getElementById("name").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("link").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("s1").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("c1").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("ex1").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("u1").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("u2").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("se1").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("ladd").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("ledit").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("lfind").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("ldel").style.display="none";
}
function addenable()
{
    document.getElementById("name").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("link").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("s1").style.display="inline";
    document.getElementById("c1").style.display="inline";
    document.getElementById("ex1").style.display="inline";
    document.getElementById("a1").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("e1").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("f1").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("d1").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("u1").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("u2").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("ladd").style.display="inline";
    document.getElementById("ledit").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("lfind").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("ldel").style.display="none";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="disableElements()">
<form method="post" action="#">
<input type="button" name="add" id="a1" value="Add" onclick="addenable()"/>
<input type="button" name="edit" id="e1" value="Edit"/>
<input type="button" name="find" id="f1" value="Find"/> 
<input type="button" name="delete" id="d1" value="Delete"/>
<input type="submit" name="save" id="s1" value="Save"/>
<input type="submit" name="update" id="u1" value="Update"/>
<input type="submit" name="remove" id="u2" value="Update"/>
<input type="reset" name="cancel" id="c1" value="Cancel"/>
<input type="button" name="exit" id="ex1" value="Exit" onclick="javascript:history.go(0);" />

    <table id="tbl1" width="100%" border="0" >
    <tr>
        <td><label>Name :</label></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Name" size="40px" id="name" /></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><label>Website :</label></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Link" size="40px" id="link" /><br/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" name="search" id="se1" value="Search"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["save"]))
{
    if(($_POST["Name"] == '') || ($_POST["Link"] == ''))
        {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("insert values....!")</script>';
        }
        else
        {
    $name = $_POST["Name"];
    $link = $_POST["Link"];

        #inserting values
        $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO data (Name, Link) VALUES ('$name','$link')");
        if(!$insert)
            {
                //die ("Error". mysql_error());
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Duplicate Entry!")</script>';
            }
        else
            {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Record Save Successflly!")</script>';
            }
    }
}

?>
```

[image]

Comment: @DarkWish can u please show me how to do this?

Comment: attach jquery file with your html and in script use like this when you want to hide something. now I m hiding name `$("#name").hide();`

Comment: There is no problem with MySQL @Cerbrus I had Checked it

Comment: Yea, I misread the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were you I'll create a function like this to cover my entire document and call alert().

```
        function hideAll(){
            var div = $('<div id="div-cover" style="background:rgba(3,3,3,.7);display:block;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;z-index:1000;"></div>');
            $(div).width($(document).width()).height($(document).height());
            $(document.body).prepend(div);
        }
        function showAll(){
            $('#div-cover').remove();
        }
```

And Call it like:

```
hideAll();
alert();
showAll();
```

AND

If you want to hide certain elements only. Give it something in common. Here I'm using html5 data attribute and javascript querySelectorAll, no jQuery.

```
    <input type="button" data-group="grp1" name="add" id="a1" value="Add" onclick="addenable()"/>
    <input type="button" data-group="grp1" name="edit" id="e1" value="Edit"/>
    <input type="button" data-group="grp1" name="find" id="f1" value="Find"/> 
    <input type="button" data-group="grp1" name="delete" id="d1" value="Delete"/>
    <input type="submit" data-group="grp1" name="save" id="s1" value="Save"/>
    <input type="submit" data-group="grp1" name="update" id="u1" value="Update"/>
    <input type="submit" data-group="grp1" name="remove" id="u2" value="Update"/>
    <input type="reset" data-group="grp1" name="cancel" id="c1" value="Cancel"/>
    <input type="button" data-group="grp1" name="exit" id="ex1" value="Exit" onclick="javascript:history.go(0);" />


    <script type="text/javascript">

        function hideAll(){
            var arr = document.querySelectorAll('[data-group="grp1"]');
            for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                arr[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
        function showAll(){
            var arr = document.querySelectorAll('[data-group="grp1"]');
            for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                arr[i].style.display = 'inline';
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: :) this is way too short. I like it but i am new to javascript its bit dificult i can't understand what is the process behind this :(

Comment: Here, I'm simply creating a div of width and height same as the document and putting it on top.

Comment: This is how I would do it +1

Comment: Oh that's pretty good, but friend i don't want to hide all the controls i just need to hide some controls like save, update, cancel and exit. that's what i need but you are right in your point of view.

Comment: Something common? as in image above, there are lots of buttons i just want to show add, edit, find and delete button, simple :)

Comment: The common attribute can be a className or andy attribute

Comment: function hideAll(){
            var arr = document.querySelectorAll('[data-group="grp1"]');
            for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                arr[i].style.display = 'none';
            }

Comment: querySelectorAll will return me with an array of all the elements with attribute data-group = 'grp1'. Then I'm looping through each elements of the array and hiding it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20109/discussion-between-bkay-and-akhil-sekharan)

Answer (score 2):

Try `$("#ex1").hide()` using jquery

Comment: Ok any parameters required for hide function?

Comment: Jquery makes JS simple, but the parameter is just a matter of using your id in the #ex1 field. The function hide is already specified in Jquery, so you have no need to write enormous long syntaxes just to hide something.

Comment: @Dorvalla i'm just close but can you please edit my code using Jquery so that i can understand the syntex.  I'll really Thankful to you

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Duplicate Entry!")</script>';
```

With:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">disableElements();alert("Duplicate Entry!");</script>';
```

That should hide the controls when the alert is called.

Comment: this is what I am looking for but here is the issue, by using this alert message also disable :(